# Python 3 Syntax error for Fahrenheit to Celsius Calculation

Tags: python, data-conversion

I'm doing a simple temperature conversion using Python 3.4.

```
#Request user's name
name = input("Hello! I'm your friendly metric conversion robot. What is your first name? ")
#Request Fahrenheit temperature
fahre = float(input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit?"))
#Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
fToC = float((fahre - 32)*(5/9))
#Display result
print(name + ", there are "+ str(format(fToC,'.2f')) + " Celsius in " + str(fahre) + " Fahrenheit degrees.")
```

I get `Syntax error: Invalid syntax (at column 5)`.

I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: The code you posted here has no syntax errors in it, your code instead works correctly. What is the *full* error message (starting from `Traceback`)

Comment: Thank you! I just tested this again and it now works fine. This is a snippet from a larger project. I'll post the original code. It's still not working correctly within the original code project.

Comment: 1st Part of Traceback: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/pythonlib/dbgp/client.py", line 2434, in runMain
    self.dbg.runfile(debug_args[0], debug_args)
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/pythonlib/dbgp/client.py", line 2021,

Comment: 2nd Part of Traceback: in runfile
    h_execfile(file, args, module=main, tracer=self)
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 8.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/pythonlib/dbgp/client.py", line 682, in __init__
    execfile(file, globals, locals)
  File "/Users/polarbear/Documents/College/ACC - APT/chase_musgrove_Lab2.py", line 16
     fahre = input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? "))
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious, this code seems to be working fine. One small adjustment I would make would be to change:

```
fahre = float(input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit?"))
```

to:

```
fahre = float(input(name + ", what is the temperature in Fahrenheit? "))
```

with a space after the question mark to make it cleaner for users. I'd also format the string of Fahrenheit as .2f to make it consistent with the Celsius .2f in the last print statement. Otherwise you wrote this fine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I tested what I posted again and now it works fine. However, this is part of a larger code project. I'll post the original where this snippet came from. It still doesn't work within the larger project for some weird reason.

Comment: Go ahead Curious and I'd be happy to take a look.